# JavaScript, HTML, JSP onClick statement

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

Is there a way to use the value from a text field as the parameter value in an onclick statement for a button. For example if you have some text field named "name" and you have another button named "button" when clicked will go to the same page "page.jsp" with a parameter "par" equal to the text field value. This is what I am currently doing:

```
out.print("<input type = 'button' name = 'noName' value = 'Click Me' onclick =" + '"' + "window.location.href = 'http://page.jsp?par=" + document.form.name.value + "'" + '"');
```

But for some reason it doesn't like the `par=" + document.form.name.value`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
<script>
    function doSomething(txt){
        alert(txt);   //alert the text maybe?
        //do more things...
    }
</script>
<input onClick="doSomething(this.value)">
```

`this.value` means the value in the textfield.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out what I was doing run.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "<input type='button' name='noName' value='Click Me' onclick="
         + "\"window.location.href='http://page.jsp?par="
         + document.form.name.value + "'\"";
```

Well, that's pretty confusing.

`document` etc. has zero meaning on the server side. Why aren't you doing this in JavaScript, where it would be a lot easier? Why isn't this in the JSP, where it would be trivial?

If you want to access a form value from a servlet, (a) that form value must have been submitted, and (b) you access it via `request.getParameter("parameterName")`. But I find it impossible to believe that's the easiest way to do it.